# Splitting a variable into separate rows

Tags: variables, split, spss

I would like to split my Variables "Wellbeing_Pre" and "Wellbeing_Post" to one Wellbeing variable and one Pre/Post-Variable, so that I have one row for each pre and post and one column for the variable "wellbeing" and one for the variable "Pre / Post" (0=pre, 1=post).

I have already a long-format in my data where there are several rows for each person for every measurment point. Now I would like to split the Pre Post Measurments to separate rows as well.

I'm grateful for ideas! :-)

Comment: Try 'varstocases'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To elaborate @horace_vr's solution:

```
varstocases make Wellbeing from Wellbeing_Pre Wellbeing_Post /index=PPtxt(Wellbeing).

* variable PPtxt now has the values "Wellbeing_Pre" and "Wellbeing_Post". 
* If you want a numeric 1/0 variable instead, do the following.

recode PPtxt ("Wellbeing_Pre"=0) ("Wellbeing_Post"=1) into Pre_Post.
exe.
```